# How to edit bitcoin.conf for bitcoin.cli scripting

Tags: script, privacy, wasabi-wallet, samourai-wallet

I want to install [Kristaps Kaupe’s scripts](https://github.com/kristapsk/bitcoin-scripts) on my bitcoin.conf but I am afraid I don't have the technical expertise necessary to make it run.

I am simply cutting and pasting it on my bitcoin.conf file, but I get an error from the start, I am sure I have to change somethings on the script in order to point to the right directory. I can manage cut and paste and entering commands on the console. Could anyone please give a simpler example showing the changes we need to make to run the script? Thank you in advance.

Comment: They aren't configuration you add to bitcoin.conf; they're separate scripts you run.

Answer (score 1):

Your link says

> Dependencies: bash, bitcoin-cli (v0.15 or newer), awk, bc, jq, sed.

which means it runs on Linux (possibly also under WSL bash shell)

you tagged your question wasabi and samouri - but those products probably don't support the necessary interface or platform, so I am unsure why you used those tags. You must be running a `bitcoin-cli` executable from [bitcoin core](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/).

Your link also says

> Scripts use Bitcoin JSON-RPC API, so it must be enabled in bitcoin.conf (server=1, rpcuser= and rpcpassword= settings).

which means you must have a `bitcoin.conf` file in the appropriate directory (`$HOME/.bitcoin/` on Linux unless you specified something else) which contains something like

```
server=1
rpcuser=digitrader21rpc
rpcpassword=jshdfvIu327840hfo8foUih24378786t5vlkjheroIJ98t-89t-!
```

Comment: btw. would you know how to specify bitcoin.conf location? `/opt/bitcoin/bin/bitcoin-cli -conf=/bitcoind/conf/bitcoin.conf createwallet "btc-wallet1"` seems not working